# How to stub defineNuxtRouteMiddleware in vitest / jest?

Tags: javascript, nuxtjs3, vitest

I have a middleware:

```
import checkAuth from './callbacks/checkAuth';
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(checkAuth);
```

I've separated `defineNuxtRouteMiddleware` call from the middleware logic and now i simply want to test that the `defineNuxtRouteMiddleware` in called with valid passed parameter. Test fails because `defineNuxtRouteMiddleware` isn't defined, how do i mock it? I've tried `vi.stubGlobal('defineNuxtRouteMiddleware', vi.fn());` but it isn't working.

Comment: _"i simply want to test that the `defineNuxtRouteMiddleware` in called with valid passed parameter"_ - I wouldn't bother doing that. Test `checkAuth` itself, and that the middleware is being applied at the integration level, but there's no behaviour here to unit test.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i thought about doing so too, thank you